# Can Magic Mouth be used to speak the verbal component of a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Could a wizard use the magic mouth ritual on an item, telling it to repeat the Verbal Component of a specific spell when the wizard touches said item, thus allowing a wizard to cast a Verbal spell without speaking? I realise that this would only ever be situationally useful, but I'm just curious to see if I am interpreting the rules on both the Magic Mouth ritual and verbal components correctly.

Comment: Historical note: In earlier editions, the Magic Mouth spell description specifically included a clause saying it couldn't be used to provide the verbal component of spells or activate magic items with command words.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### No.

> **PHB, pg 203**
>
> If you can't provide one or more of a spell's components, you are unable to cast the spell.

When you cast *Magic Mouth* you are embedding a message in a usually mundane object to be spoken at another time.  It is physically the object that speaks the words.  Since *you* are not providing the spell's components, *you* are unable to cast the spell.

Comment: As a clarification, the Verbal component rules are not satisfied that the "magical mouth appears on the object and recites the message in your voice and at the same volume you spoke", as being an excuse that it actually IS your voice giving the verbal command?

Comment: Are *you* speaking the words?  If yes, they satisfy the requirement.  If no, they do not.  In the case of the spell, though it may be in your voice at your volume, it is specifically the object that speaks the words.  As an aside, past editions of D&D have explicitly ruled out using *Magic Mouth* to fulfill verbal spell components so this is in line with established expectations of what the spell is capable of doing.

Comment: In addition to that, it's probably the same thing with Mage Hand and Mage Hand Ledermain: the spell per se is too rough to execute finesse movements (such as pickpocketing or lockpicking), and the verbal component is a very precise combination of hums and pitches.

Answer (score 7):

No

The object Magic Mouth was cast on speaks the words. To cast a spell with a verbal component *you* need to speak the words.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it would not complete the spell properly.

Casting a spell involves focusing the mystical energy to do what you want. As you allow the energy to flow through you, your esoteric intonations, your practiced gestures, and your carefully prepared bits of fluff and pinches of dusts all serve to focus the spell to its purpose, guiding its energies.

When *you* are casting the spell and *you* speak the words, *you* are focusing the energy that is flowing through *you*. It could be any source speaking the words that is not you, and it would still not focus the spell correctly.

It's the same as spells that have a Verbal component only. You can't simply mumble the appropriate words and have the spell go off as often as you'd like. It also requires that you channel the power to make the spell work.

If I were DM'ing it, I would allow an exception for a warlock who has taken the "Voice of the Chain Master" invocation, and has their familiar in physical contact with them during the casting, due to the already strong metaphysical bond between a familiar and its master.